# Puse en minuscula los campos pero aun aparece Error 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando correr el `script` exportado de un modelo relacional que hice usando **MySQL WorkBench**, pero al intentar crear la bd me aparece un error, el cual he buscado, y me dice que es debido a que el nombre de algunos campos estan en mayusculas, pues los puse en minuscula y aun sigue saliendo, dejare por aqui el codigo y una imagen de la bd.

#### Script SQL

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 09/07/17 14:40:25
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Roles` (
  `idRoles` INT NOT NULL,
  `tipoRol` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRoles`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Personas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Personas` (
  `idPersonas` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombres_Persona` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `apellidos_Persona` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonas`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Usuarios`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Usuarios` (
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Roles_idRoles` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Personas_idPersonas` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  INDEX `fk_Usuarios_Roles_idx` (`Roles_idRoles` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Usuarios_Personas1_idx` (`Personas_idPersonas` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuarios_Roles`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Roles_idRoles`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Roles` (`idRoles`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuarios_Personas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Personas_idPersonas`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Personas` (`idPersonas`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Facultades`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Facultades` (
  `idFacultades` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombreFacultad` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFacultades`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Programas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Programas` (
  `idProgramas` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombrePrograma` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Facultades_idFacultades` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProgramas`),
  INDEX `fk_Programas_Facultades1_idx` (`Facultades_idFacultades` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Programas_Facultades1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Facultades_idFacultades`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Facultades` (`idFacultades`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Asignatura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Asignatura` (
  `idAsignatura` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_Asignatura` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `creditos` INT NULL,
  `Programas_idProgramas` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAsignatura`),
  INDEX `fk_Asignatura_Programas1_idx` (`Programas_idProgramas` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Asignatura_Programas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Programas_idProgramas`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Programas` (`idProgramas`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Grupos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Grupos` (
  `idGrupos` INT NOT NULL,
  `numeroGrupo` INT NOT NULL,
  `Asignatura_idAsignatura` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGrupos`),
  INDEX `fk_Grupos_Asignatura1_idx` (`Asignatura_idAsignatura` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Grupos_Asignatura1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Asignatura_idAsignatura`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Asignatura` (`idAsignatura`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Calificaciones`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Calificaciones` (
  `idCalificaciones` INT NOT NULL,
  `nota_1` FLOAT NULL,
  `nota_2` FLOAT NULL,
  `nota_3` FLOAT NULL,
  `Habilitacion` FLOAT NULL,
  `Grupos_idGrupos` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCalificaciones`),
  INDEX `fk_Calificaciones_Grupos1_idx` (`Grupos_idGrupos` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Calificaciones_Grupos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Grupos_idGrupos`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Grupos` (`idGrupos`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Horario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Horario` (
  `lugar` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dia` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `hora` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Grupos_idGrupos` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_Horario_Grupos1_idx` (`Grupos_idGrupos` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Horario_Grupos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Grupos_idGrupos`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Grupos` (`idGrupos`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Personas_Grupos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Personas_Grupos` (
  `Personas_idPersonas` INT NOT NULL,
  `Grupos_idGrupos` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Personas_idPersonas`, `Grupos_idGrupos`),
  INDEX `fk_Personas_has_Grupos_Grupos1_idx` (`Grupos_idGrupos` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Personas_has_Grupos_Personas1_idx` (`Personas_idPersonas` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Personas_has_Grupos_Personas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Personas_idPersonas`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Personas` (`idPersonas`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Personas_has_Grupos_Grupos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Grupos_idGrupos`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Grupos` (`idGrupos`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

#### Modelo relacional

[image: modelo e-r]

Comment: Mas parece que se esta intentando agreagar una llave foranea a una tabla que no existe

Comment: ¿En qué línea salta el error? ¿En cuál de todas las tablas no te permite agregar la referencia de la llave foránea? Sugiero que tomes el [tour] y de igual forma veas la forma adecuada de [ask] ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error esta en la definición del campo `Roles_idRoles` en la tabla `Usuarios`.

Para poder crear una clave foránea **el tipo de dato** de `Usuarios.Roles_idRoles`, deber ser igual al de `Roles.idRoles`.

### Solución:

Modificar esto

```
`Roles_idRoles` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
```

A esto

```
`Roles_idRoles` INT NOT NULL,
```

Código de tabla completo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Usuarios` (
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Roles_idRoles` INT NOT NULL,
  `Personas_idPersonas` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  INDEX `fk_Usuarios_Roles_idx` (`Roles_idRoles` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Usuarios_Personas1_idx` (`Personas_idPersonas` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuarios_Roles`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Roles_idRoles`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Roles` (`idRoles`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuarios_Personas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Personas_idPersonas`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Personas` (`idPersonas`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: probando, y respondiendo si sirve

Comment: Funciono perfectamente, gracias